# Adding additional hot swap drive to HP ProLiant DL360 in RAID1 config

Tags: hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, raid1, hotswap

I have a HP ProLiant DL360p Gen8 server. It has 8 drive bays with only 6 being used in a RAID1 config.

Can I add an additional 2 drives to the empty bays hot and the HP Smart Array Controller will configure them automatically into the RAID and they'll appear as one logical drive or do I have to power down the server and configure them manually in the HP Intelligent Provisioning utility like I did with the original 6 drives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this live with the [HP Smart Storage Administrator](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5409020) utility for your operating system.

The process is called an *array transformation*.